# Rename multiple files with special character _ to?

Tags: linux, rename, mv

I have a bunch of files that are data.html_XYZ that I have to rename to data.html?XYZ in the same folder. I've tried using rename and mv but keep getting errors since they are special characters. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming

Comment: Simply, you cannot have `?` in your file name.

Comment: @Irfan434 In fact you can.

Comment: @Irfan434 you can't on windows but you can on linux.

Comment: @Michael, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [escape character](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) `\` before special characters as `?`:

```
mv data.html_XYZ data.html\?XYZ
```